How do we get a single chart to cover an incomplete, connected Riemannian manifold almost everywhere? Will exponential map be a diffeomorphism on it?
Below, our setup is the calculation for $\int_{M}f(x)d{\rm vol}_g(x), dim(M)=d, f:(M,g)\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous (or more as needed).$(M,g)$ is an incomplete, connected Riemannian manifold (geodesically and therefore, metrically, by Hopf-Rinow theorem). $M$ arises e.g. the interior of a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary.
My question is motivated by

this question

the need to write the integral $\int_{M}f(x)d{\rm vol}_g(x)$ as $\int_{U\subset \mathbb{R}^d}f\circ \phi (u) \sqrt{det (g)(u)}du $ for a suitable for a suitable open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ of full Riemannian volume measure on $M.$


When $M$ is complete, the answer is the exponential map applied to the inside of the cut locus. But when $M$ is incomplete, we don't talk about cut point or cut locus in general, since there may not be any geodesics joining two points. But nonetheless, will we always have such a chart $(U, \phi)$ covering $M$ almost everywhere, and if yes, how do we construct it?
For some simple examples:

If we we know that $M$  to be an open subset of  $\tilde{M},$ a complete Riemannian manifold, we can simply take $U$ to be the the intersection of the $M$ with the interior of the cut locus (also called segment domain) of $ \tilde{M}, i.e. U:= M\setminus cut(\tilde{M})$ and $\phi$ to be the restriction of the exponential map of $ \tilde{M}$ to $M\setminus Cut(\tilde{M}) $ then  $U$ is an open subset of full Riemannian measure in $M.$

However, if $M$ is a proper submanifold and not an open subset of the complete Riemannian manifold $\tilde{M},$ then $cut(\tilde{M})$ may have positive measure in $M,$ so the above $U$ may not work...?

If we take $M$ to be the interior of compact Riemannian manifold $\overline{M}$ with boundary (this is definitely an important example for me), then $M$ can be isometrically embedded into, and thus can be thought of an open subset of the double $\tilde(M)$ of the manifold $\overline{M}$ with boundary, and thus we're back to example 1) above.


But in general, how can we construct an open, full Riemannian measure subset $U$ of $M$ that's covered by a single chart $\phi,$ hopefully an exponential/normal chart?

You could choose a complete Riemannian metric on $M$ (such a metric always exists), and use the exponential map for that metric.

In fact, to integrate differential forms or densities you do not need this for integration, just use a partition of unity. This is how it is done in all standard textbooks.

@JackLee Thanks for your comment. But the metric $g$ is prechosen, and we can't change it in my question.

@LearningMath: All you asked for is a chart covering all of $M$ but a set of measure zero. You can use the exponential map of a different metric to construct such a chart, and then just forget it was an exponential map. It's a chart of the type you seek.

@JackLee Okay thanks, I get it now. So we just choose a complete Riemannian metric on $M$ as you first suggested, and take out the cut locus which has full measure w.r.t. any two Riemannian metrics (the complete and the incomplete) and hence the complement of the cut locus of the complete metric will have a full measure.
I agree, thanks again. It's just that I'm wondering how we could construct such a full measure chart where the original exponential map (of the incomplete metric) is a diffeomorphism.

@JackLee . I'm interested in exploring how we can generalize the concept of cut locus for incomplete metrics. But I agree that in my original post, I didn't mention this.

@MoisheKohan hanks for your comment: I think you're asking to write $f=\sum_k f\psi_k$ using a partion of unity $\psi_k, 1 \le k \le r,$ and then write $\int_M f= \sum_k \int_{U_k}f\psi_k$
.
Is this correct? But I was wondering if we can have just one single chart have a single chart $(U,ϕ)$
so that $U$
has complete $vol_g$
measure, when $M$
is incomplete. My question was: is it possible? And if yes, how do we construct it?

This was asked and answered several times. Yes, you can, but cut-locus makes no sense in this setting and I do not understand the motivation anymore.
